# How set cursor inside textbox after page load with jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, text-cursor

Alright i have a asp.net textbox and i want to set cursor inside textbox after page loaded like when you open google.

I only need set cursor inside textbox code.

I tried this but not working

```
$('txtSendTo').focus();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If `txtSendTo` is an `id`, you need a `#`

`$('#txtSendTo').focus();`

---

If `txtSendTo` is a `class`, you need a `.`

`$('.txtSendTo').focus();`

---

Or, if there is only one `textbox` on the page

`$('textbox').focus();`

---

Also make sure the page is fully loaded before you try to search the dom:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  `$('textbox').focus();`
});
```

Comment: ye it is id and i am executing after page load as focus but not working.  inside  $(document).ready(function () {   and using clientidmode static so id is correct

Comment: If it's an `id` then you need to reference it as `#txtSendTo` with the `#`.

Comment: Definitely happens @MonsterMMORPG.  Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to set cursor inside an input field when a link is clicked. However adding event.preventDefault() at the start of the function and returning false fixed it. Here is the code if someone is having the same issue

```
$("#search-button").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#textbox").focus();
  return false;
});
```